# Adding product() method to Collection with metaClass

Tags: list, groovy, product, metaclass

I would like to add a method `product()` to all collections and use it like I can use `sum()`.
I can already get the product of a list by going `x.inject { a, b -> a * b }`, but I would like to be able to go `x.product()`.

So far I have tried

```
Collection.metaClass.product = {-> delegate.inject { a, b -> a * b } }

x = [1,2,3,4]
println(x.product())
```

But this results in

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.inject() is applicable for argument types: (Util$_run_closure1_closure2) values: [Util$_run_closure1_closure2@161bb7fe]
Possible solutions: inject(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure), inject(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure), inspect(), toSet(), collect(), collect()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.inject() is applicable for argument types: (Util$_run_closure1_closure2) values: [Util$_run_closure1_closure2@161bb7fe]
Possible solutions: inject(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure), inject(java.lang.Object, groovy.lang.Closure), inspect(), toSet(), collect(), collect()
    at Util$_run_closure1.doCall(Util.groovy:1)
    at Util.run(Util.groovy:4)
```

Comment: Could you please refactore your finding as the answer. Then press accept your own answer.

Comment: What version of groovy is this?

Comment: You can use `product()` as a wrapper of `sum()` method:
`Collection.metaClass.product = { delegate.sum() }`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that can be tested by running the code in the Groovy Console

```
// implement method
Collection.metaClass.product = {

  if (!delegate) {
    return null
  }

  delegate.inject {a, b ->  a * b}
}

// test it
assert [1,2,3].product() == 6
assert [].product() == null
```

A slightly longer, but more readable (IMO) solution is:

```
Collection.metaClass.product = {

  if (!delegate) {
    return null
  }

  def result = 1

  delegate.each {
    result *= it
  }
  result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

For whatever utterly bizarre reason, groovysh allowed `x.inject { a, b -> a * b }`, but this exploded when I actually compiled it outside of groovysh. Once changed to `x.inject(1) { a, b -> a * b }`, everything works as expected.